# Why does Alluka only have the strength of a normal child?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

It has been stated clearly that Alluak Zoldyck has the same amount of power of a normal child, which in the Hunter x Hunter universe means that he/she is very weak.

[image: Killua vs Illumi]

However, all other children in the [Zoldyck family](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Zoldyck_Family) have received training since a very early age as well as possessing a set of talents that unique to the family, such as resistance to poison, strength and resistance to pain, even before learning nen.

Until they found out about Alluka's wish granting ability, there was nothing to suggest he/she was different from the other siblings. Therefore, it could be assumed that he/she should have received the same training as his/her siblings before that.

So why does she only have the power of a normal child?

Comment: so which are you trying to ask? why she, err.. he,  didn't have training?

Comment: what do you mean by normal? that alluka didn't become an assassin who takes jobs like alluka's brothers?

Comment: It's possible that he was never trained like the others because there were complications around his birth resulting in being born without a soul. Just a guess that his parents put him under supervision and didn't train him because they didn't think of him as human.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that, until Alluka evidenced dangerous powers, there is no clear reason why Alluka would not have received any Zoldyck assassin training from a very young age.  However, a statement that Alluka has the physical strength of a normal child does *not* tell us whether or not Alluka received any special training prior to entering solitary confinement.

Killua's brother Milluki, who we do know has undergone the standard training, does not demonstrate having any special amount of physical strength (he easily tired of whipping Killua due to exertion in [chapter 42](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Milluki_Zoldyck) of volume 5). He also does not display any Nen abilities. It could well be that he only has the physical strength of an average overweight teenage boy his age and his assassin training was solely in areas other than physical prowess.

Killua's mother Kikyo, who has undergone the standard training, also does not show examples of physical strength. Physically, we only know that 1) she can run at high speeds and 2) she was able to hold Killua by the arm in order to try to keep him from leaving, but since she willingly decided to let him go, we do not know if she is necessarily physically stronger than him or not (i.e. if she had wanted to make him to stay, could she have kept him pinned there by physical force, or could he have wrested away on his own strength? [same [chapter](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Kikyo_Zoldyck)]).

Comment: Milluki seemed confident that he could kill Gon, Kurapika and Leorio in the Zoldyck arc as he threatened to kill them. Killua reacted as though this was a possibility. Would that mean Milluki has no physical prowess and thought of killing them another way?